# LaTeX notation for this special L symbol

Tags: symbols

[image]

What is the LaTeX notation for the L in the A* map? I've never seen it before. It couldn't be identified by any tools.

Comment: (I tried font squirrel, shape catcher, deTeXify, whatthefont, doesn't work. Whether [Find the Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140532/250119) work or not I don't know, the program is not free) On the other hand the PDF-info method in the specified question should work, if you have PDF.

Comment: I guess deTeXify etc. are not allowed to include them because the fonts are not free, but if they do the program should be able to detect the character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's produced by `\mathcal{L}` whose appearance is different with different fonts used by `\mathcal{}`.

The text and math fonts are Adobe Minion Pro series which could be called by the [`MinionPro`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/) package. And the mathcal letters are the swash capitals from the `MinionPro` package for which see the following screen shot from the Adobe Minion Pro Italic font in which appearances of letters may be a little different with different versions.

[image]

If you can call the `MinionPro` package, please add the `swash` option.

```
\usepackage[swash]{MinionPro}
```

Comment: How would you get the right font? Cause right now its not showing up the same

Comment: @junglekarmapizza I update the answer.